# JSON parsing in ArrayList in ListFragment throwing getApplicationContext() error

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, arraylist

I'm developing an app which displays some basic parsed JSON in `ListFragment`. 
I followed http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial and it was working well in `ListActivity`. Then I started making my own app. I made new project in Android Studio 1.5, added Navigation Drawer Activity since I have some more stuff to do/display and started to rewriting the code into a fragment. This was basically easy except one crazy issue with `getApplicationContext()` and `Cannot resolve method getApplciationContext()` error which is still unresolved.

Here is part of my fragment:

```
public class Den1Fragment extends ListFragment {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_den1, container, false);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), // TODO error!
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}
```

If I add `Intent in = new Intent(**getActivity().**getApplicationContext(), SingleContactActivity.class);` errors moves to `contactList = new ArrayList<>();` and Android Studio has no idea how to solve it and even Googling didn't bring much wanted results.
I tried to do it again with different order of rewriting and found out that if I leave `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` instead of changing it to `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_den1, container, false);`, the setContentView become red but contactList line stays "OK".

**EDIT**

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

bugreport:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.ludato.festapp/cz.ludato.festapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at cz.ludato.festapp.Den1Fragment.onViewCreated(Den1Fragment.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public class Den1Fragment extends ListFragment {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
private JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<>();;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_den1, container, false);
ListView lv = getListView();

// Listview on item click listener
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                .getText().toString();
        String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                .getText().toString();
        String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                .getText().toString();

        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleContactActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
        in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
        in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
        getActivity().startActivity(in); 

    }
});

// Calling async task to get json
new GetContacts().execute();

return view;
}
```

Comment: Cool. But now I got really strange error. Code + bugreport added.

Comment: Try to replace the ID of your ListView to android:id="@+id/list"

Comment: Lol. I just realized that I need to add the listview to fragment_den1.xml